# How can I get a count on each instance of a model's "hasMany" relationship when I am retrieving lots of data in CakePHP?

Tags: php, cakephp, model-view-controller, cakephp-2.0

*NB: My title was quite difficult to word - If you think of a way to word it more concisely I would appreciate that.*

I'm using CakePHP and I am making a basic forum system. My models are set out as follows:

`ForumSection has many ForumCategories
ForumCategory has many ForumPosts, has one ForumSection
ForumPost has many ForumPosts, has one ForumCategory (NB: ForumPost can be a thread or a reply)`

On the index page of the forum, I would like to display the number of posts and replies in each forum category. I can do this by implementing the Containable relationship (which I have) into my ForumSection model and then using the following statement:

```
    $sections = $this->ForumSection->find('all', array(
        'contain' => array(
            'ForumCategory' => array(
                'ForumPost' => array(
                    'conditions' => array('ForumPost.is_thread', '1')
                )
            )
        )
    ));
```

Then, on my view, I can simply echo the count of ForumPosts.

This is, of course, suboptimal -- I could be potentially bringing back thousands upon thousands of rows of data and loading it into memory when in reality I could do a direct SQL along the lines of `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ForumPosts WHERE forum_category_id = x AND is_thread = 1` for count and avoid this. I could even use a Cake function to do this for me but the point stands that it's more efficient than loading the entire table into memory just to count them.

This would, though, require making a loop in my controller (or model potentially but I'd still need to loop the sections in the controller) and meddling with the returned data so as to insert counts into it.

The way I see it, I have two options:

1. I could, in the view, get the post count as I loop over the categories, e.g.

`foreach ($categories as $category):
// get post count
echo post count`

I am reluctant to do this since, to my knowledge, this seems to ill-advised on MVC projects and I'm certain there'll be a more optimal approach I have not considered.

2. Intercept the found data and insert counts before patching the data through to the view. This seems like the most true to MVC way of doing it but it still feels wrong.

My question, ultimately, is does Cake provide any way of including the count of a model's inner relationships without including the entire data set for said relationship? If not, is there an approach that I could take that would be more straightforward/follow conventions more effectively than my suggested two?

Comment: The question is well written, which is really nice for a change. However this has been discussed many times already, the answer is "Counter Cache". I'm halfway sleeping already, and too tired to search for the proper duplicate, so here's just a link to the docs: **http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#countercache-cache-your-count**

Comment: I saw that mentioned while I was trying to find an answer, but was hoping to find a way of doing a run-time calculation -- In retrospect, I don't really have any good reason for wanting to it at run-time (other than an at-times irrational developed distaste of storing derivable data), so I think I'll implement that. If you post that as an answer I'll accept it -- Thanks! (And my apologies for the duplicate; I'm not sure of the procedure to follow - do I close/delete the question?)